# Exception in Progress Bar-WPF

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, object-reference

Iam using a Progress bar to show the progress of loading features, ini WPF. The xaml code looks like this,

```
  <Grid>
   <ProgressBar Height="13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,117,0,0" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291" Value="0" IsIndeterminate="True" />
  <Grid>
```

and in code behind,

```
   public SplashScreen()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();         

        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(30.0, duration);

        progressBar1.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty,doubleanimation); //Exception

    }
```

While executing the code, it throws me an exception in the last line stating that **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**.

Can anyone help me to overcome this exception and to make my progressbar work.

Comment: It must be something else because it works here. You should check the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get that `Exception` on the last line, then the *only* object on that line that *could* be `null` is your `progressBar1` object. Only you can tell why it is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the exception occurs. Since iam using the code in Constructor, am encountering the exception. When Iam using the same in load_event(), no problem....